# mobile dropdown navigation not appearing below 1024px wide

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, responsive

This is weird. I have some pretty straightforward styling and code to make a dropdown menu appear if the screen is less than 1150px wide. What happens is, the dropdown does appear if the screen is more than 1024px side and less than 1150px wide, but below 1024px wide, it disappears (!).

I don't seem to have any styles that would make this dropdown menu disappear (at all). Does anyone know what is happening?

https://jsfiddle.net/LNMSchneiderman/62ecg453/16/

html:

```
<navbar  >
     <leftalign>
             
             <span class="navbar-head2" style="">Project</span>
     </leftalign>

        <rightalign>
            <span class="desktop-nav"><a class="current-page" href="index.php">Introduction</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="">Penn </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="">Homewood</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="">Ohio</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="">Carson </a> </span>

            <span class="mobile-nav hamburger"><i class="fas fa-bars "></i></span>

                <ul class="dropdownL" >
                      <li class="intro" id="intro"><a href="">Introduction</a></li>
                      <li class="intro" id="pennave"><a href="">Penn </a></li>
                        <li class="intro" id="homewood"><a href="">Homewood</a></li>
                      <li class="intro" id="eastohio"><a href="">Ohio</a></li>
                      <li class="intro" id="eastcarson"><a href="">Carson</a></li>

                </ul>

            

        </rightalign>
 </navbar>
```

css:

```
navbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background: #f2f2eb;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 10px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 3000;
    opacity: 1;
   transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.navbar-head2 {
    font-family: 'proxima-nova', Helevtica, Verdana, sans-serif; color: #000;
   letter-spacing: .1rem; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 5px; font-weight: 700;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .navbar-head2 {
        margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    }
}



 navbar leftalign, navbar rightalign {
        width: auto;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
        navbar leftalign {
            justify-content: flex-start;
        }
    }
    
    navbar rightalign {
        margin-right: 30px;
        margin-top: -9px;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
        navbar rightalign {
            margin-right: 10px;
            margin-top: -5px;
        }
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
        navbar {
            display:block;
            position: fixed;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    
        navbar rightalign {
            position: absolute;
            right:0;
            top: 0;
        }
        
    }
    .hamburger {
      cursor: pointer;
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      margin-right: 40px;
    }
    
    .dropdownL {
      position: fixed;
      top: 75px;
      right: 0vw;
      list-style-type: none !important;
      z-index:10;
      margin-left: 0;
      height: auto;
      width: 200px;
      display: none;
    }
    
      .dropdownL li  {
        padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
        color: black;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
        font-family: 'proxima-nova', sans-serif;
    
    
      }
      .dropdownL li:last-child {
        border-bottom: none 0;
      }
      .dropdownL li:hover {
        opacity: .9;
      }
    
      .dropdownL li a:link, .dropdownL li a:visited, .dropdownL li a:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        padding-left: 0;
        color: black !important;
        font-weight: 400;
      }
      
      .desktop-nav {
      display: block;
      margin-right: 40px;
    }
    
    .mobile-nav {
      display: none;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1150px) {
        .mobile-nav {
            display: block !important;
        }
        .desktop-nav {
            display: none;
        }
    }
```

jquery:

```
$('.hamburger').on('click', function(e) {
                    if ( $( ".dropdownL li:first" ).is( ":hidden" ) ) {
                    $( ".dropdownL" ).slideDown( "slow" );
                  } else {
                    $( ".dropdownL" ).slideUp();
                  }

            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you were just hiding it!

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
navbar {
    display:block;
    position: fixed;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
}
```

If you remove the hidden overflow, you will be able to see the dropdown everywhere else.

Adding this will ensure that after the desktop nav shows, the mobile will disappear.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1167px) {
.dropdownL {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Here is the fixed version: https://jsfiddle.net/fq0Ly478/1/

Comment: Thank you!! The overflow was the real trick.